# forEach iterations in angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
 data.forEach((element) => {
          const distance = this.distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(this.Senderlat,
            this.Senderlng,parseFloat(element.lat),parseFloat(element.lng));
```

the above forEach loop returns some values..how can i loop through it, to put in certain conditions for the constant distance

Comment: what exactly you need ?

Comment: sorry for my late response..i want to get the closes distance my current location from the provided coordinates